# Tradução dos nomes de algumas filas de análise

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização, filas-de-análise

As seguintes três das [filas de análises](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review) têm traduções ruins:

- Votos encerrados
- Votos reabertos
- Últimas respostas

Sugiro mudarmos para:

- Votos para fechar
- Votos para reabrir
- Respostas tardias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que encontrei tudo. Vai pro ar no próximo build.

Comment: Já está no ar :)