# Tradução em página de análise - Primeiras publicações

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha sugestão:

> Analisar as primeiras publicações de novos usuários

Além disso, também tem que corrigir as traduções sugeridas [nesse post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/206/3117), e consequentemente suas descrições.

Comment: Concordo com a sua sugestão: `Analisar as primeiras publicações de novos usuários`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added an override as suggested, available in build rev `2014.2.28.1410`.